# Flow JS $Keys with generic

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Anyone know why this doesn't work and how to fix? I am trying to say that the `onChange` function takes a `key` from the generic `State` as it's argument. But it's not working the way I thought it would.

```js
function test<State>() {
    const onChange = (key: $Keys<State>) => {}
    return onChange;
}

const INITIAL = { foo: 'bar' };

function hey() {
    const change = test<typeof INITIAL>();

    // Error here
    // Cannot call `change` with `'foo'` bound to `key` because property `foo` is missing in `State`
    change('foo');
}
```

https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgMpQIaoB8AFAJSIDeAUAJAQIaIIDCAFnmAOYqIC8ixANYoAngC5EAEgDSotDnxFyvQpQC+VRFsQAnFFBA6kLdlxQBuKhqr0wjAJIA5ewBV7AQQAyfSomBw4CQByACM8HSDENUsqUEhYBERWUTJKTToGKEQIU24fVAxMKBEABxQ4YEQnVw9PElJLLTpclGIg-zgghqsgA

Answer (score 0):

Typing the return type of the function fixes it.

```js
function test<State: {}>(): (key: $Keys<State>) => void {
    const onChange = (key) => {}
    return onChange;
}
const INITIAL = { foo: 'bar' };
function hey() {
    const change = test<typeof INITIAL>();
    change('foo');
}
```

https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgMpQIaoBciA3gL4B8AFAJTFUDWKAnsQCQDSLaO+qFNRAF4KiAG5wYAE1IAoAJAQEGRAgDCACzxgA5imGJGLQSNJlZiS4gBOKKCGtJ1W3SgDcs80rAqAkgDlfABVfAEEAGQMSRGA4OGIAcgAjPGsExDIPUEhYBEQNFlo5REVlKEQIFz0DVAxMKGYABxQ4YEQA4LDw6hoPS0UqlCoE2LgE3s8gA